# Преобразовать запросы в msqli

Tags: php

Преобразовать соединения базы данных с pdo на msqli

```
   //массивы соответствий для обычных полей и чекбоксов 
    $fields     = array(
        'title' => 'name_cafe',
        'street' => 'street_cafe',
        'city' => 'city_cafe'
    );
    $checkboxes = array(
        'wifi' => 'prefix1',
        'bil' => 'prefix2',
        'sush' => 'prefix3',
        'kal' => 'prefix4',
        'kar' => 'prefix5',
        'nal' => 'prefix6'
    );
    //составляем запрос:
    $req        = array();
    $vals       = array();
    foreach ($fields as $k => $field) {
        if (array_key_exists($k, $_POST)) {
            $req[]  = '`' . $field . '` like ?';
            $vals[] = '%' . $_POST[$k] . '%';
        }
    }
    foreach ($checkboxes as $k => $checkbox) {
        if (array_key_exists($k, $_POST)) {
            $req[] = '`' . $checkbox . '`=1';
        }
    }
    if ($req) {
        //подключаемся к базе
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
        $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE " . implode(' or ', $req));
        $db->execute($vals);
        $result = $db->fetchAll();
        print_r($result);
    }
```

Comment: Уточните, в суть вопроса.

Comment: С pdo на msqli преобразовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE " . implode(' or ', $req));
if ($stmt->errno) {
    die('Select Error (' . $stmt->errno . ') ' . $stmt->error);
}
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$stmt->close();

$row = $result->fetch_all();
```